# Export Html table contents to CSV file with custom file name (should work in IE)

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am a newbie to web programming and I am trying to save the contents of a Html table to a CSV file. the CSV file needs to have a custom file name and should work in IE, FF and Chrome. This is my requirement.

Here's what I have:

```
input.addEventListener('click', function (e) 
{
  var fileName = cntrySel.value + '-Data.csv';
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var data=$('#output').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
  blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' }); //new way
  var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = fileName;
  a.href = csvUrl;
  a.click();
  a.setAttribute('onClick','');
  e.preventDefault();
```

});

The code above is working in FF and Chrome (not in IE) and is using the Html5 download attribute. But to make it work in IE I started looking at XmlHttpRequest.

Code below modified to include XmlHttpRequest:

```
  input.addEventListener('click', function (e) 
  {
    var fileName = cntrySel.value + '-Data.csv';
    var data=$('#output').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
    blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
    var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", csvUrl, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName");  

    xhr.send(null); 


     if (xhr.status !== 200) throw new Error(xhr.statusText);
        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
        if (!type.match(/^text/)) 
            throw new Error("Expected textual response; got: " + type);

     return xhr.responseText;
    });
```

In the debugger, I can xhr.responseText has the dataset I am looking for. However I don't have a clue on how to save this data to CSV with a custom filename with this working across all browsers.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this library:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

```
FileSaver.js implements the W3C saveAs() FileSaver interface in browsers that do not natively support it.
```

Here's a demo

http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

You send the data and a file's name and type

OR, to save only CSV you have this simple javascript

```
var myCsv = "Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3";
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));
```

ofcourse this myCsv var is your data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the window.open option but it did not work in IE and I was not sure how to specify a file name. So I am looking at FileSaver.js and when I included it in my js file, I am getting this message "Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. "